# Instantiate a jagged array with JSON syntax

Tags: c#, xsd.exe

I have an XSD.exe generated class.  I am using a crude inversion of control.  My test object worked until I added this fancy XML snippet:

```
  <items>
    <item>
      <model>1000</model>
      <description>Torque wrench</description>
      <material>1545454</material>
      <lot>3</lot>
      <serial></serial>
      <transferQty>1</transferQty>
      <shipQty></shipQty>
    </item>
    <item>
         //..item 2
    </item>
    <item>
          //...item 3
    </item>
  </items>
</itemOrder>
```

Now, GeneratedByXsdClass object creation is busted.

```
    GeneratedByXsdClass.items = new itemOrderItemsItem[][]{
        new itemOrderItemsItem[1][]//this hardcoded 1 bothers me.  better way?
        {
            new itemOrderItemsItem[]
            {
                new itemOrderItemsItem()
                {
                    model = "1000",
                    description = "Torque Wrench",
                    material = "10002525",
                    lot = "3",
                    serial = "",
                    transferQty = "1",
                    shipQty = ""
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Compiler Error:

```
Error   3   Cannot implicitly convert type 'itemOrderItemsItem[][]' to 'itemOrderItemsItem[]'
```

I'm open to modifying the xsd.exe generated class if that makes life easier.  I really just want `<item>` to repeat N times.

Comment: What does this have to do with Json?

Comment: I thought the syntax im using to instantiate the properties was a JSON syntax.  Is that incorrect?

Comment: Json is a data format with a syntax that is a subset of Javascript. What you have is an example of c#'s inline object initialization syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplify your example down to this:

```
new int[][]{
    new int[1][]//this hardcoded 1 bothers me.  better way?
    {
        new int[]
        {
            4
        }
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to see what the problem is; you're trying to put an `int[][]` inside an `int[][]`, and the compiler is saying it expected a `int[]`. Remove the line with the comment:

```
new int[][]{
    new int[]
    {
        4
    }
}
```

This is the equivalent in your code:

```
GeneratedByXsdClass.items = new itemOrderItemsItem[][]{
    new itemOrderItemsItem[]
    {
        new itemOrderItemsItem()
        {
            model = "1000",
            description = "Torque Wrench",
            material = "10002525",
            lot = "3",
            serial = "",
            transferQty = "1",
            shipQty = ""
        }
    }
};
```